# When will the java date collapse?

Tags: java, datetime

AFAIK java stores dates in long variables as milliseconds. Consequently someday there will be no value (cause long has a maximum) which will correspond to the time of that instant. Do you know when it will happen?

Comment: I believe the sun is expected to go nova before then.  Sun has already gone nova.

Comment: Actually, I have that wrong - Java Date has 292 million years, but according to http://www.space.com/scienceastronomy/solarsystem/death_of_earth_000224.html the earth has 500 million years.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978452/when-will-system-currenttimemillis-overflow

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's easy enough to find out:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new java.util.Date(Long.MAX_VALUE));
    }
}
```

Gives output (on my box):

```
Sun Aug 17 07:12:55 GMT 292278994
```

You may need to subtract a bit from `Long.MAX_VALUE` to cope with your time zone overflowing the range of long, but it will give a reasonable ballpark :)

Comment: I like it too :-) It even gives the second it will break ;)

Comment: No, no, no... it breaks one millisecond AFTER the time posted.  If it was displaying milliseconds, that is.

Answer (score 28):

According to the current [leap-year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) regulations the average number of days per year will be

365 + 1/4 − 1/100 + 1/400 = 365.2425 days per year

This means that we, in average, have 31556952000 milliseconds per year.

The long-value represents the number of milliseconds since the [Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch) (1st of January, 1970) and the maximum number represented by a Java long is 2<sup>63</sup> − 1, so the following calculation

1970 + (2<sup>63</sup> − 1) / 31556952000

reveals that this representation will overflow year 292278994.

---

This can, as [Jon Skeet points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4195068/276052), be confirmed by

```
-> System.out.println(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE));
Sun Aug 17 08:12:55 CET 292278994
```

Comment: With such large numbers being used as dates, leap seconds and tidal acceleration probably need to be factored in too.

Comment: @Qwerky, yeah, I thought about that too, and search for astronomical measurements of the number of milliseconds of a year, but then it struck me that the question was about the java date-implementation, and this does most likely *not* take tidal acceleration etc into account :-)