# What happens after 2038-1-19?

Tags: integer, epoch

Starting with the epoch time

> 1 January 1970 00:00:00

and counting to the limit a 32-bit signed integer can reach, the day when we reach the limit of counting time (in computer, of course) is 2038-1-19, as given in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090869/why-is-1-1-1970-the-epoch-time) by Matt Howells.

> a 32-bit signed integer using 1970-1-1 as its epoch can represent dates up to 2038-1-19, on which date it will wrap around to 1901-12-13

If it wraps around to a back date, what then is the solution to count the time forward instead of wrapping to back date? As given in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

> There is no universal solution for the Year 2038 problem.

I don't feel comfortable about this! There must be some thought as to the solution to this problem. I understand the cause for not using a 64-bit integer in the first place (which would give us 292 billion years to relax!): not many machines could (could any?) handle 64-bit integers that time. And switching to a 64-bit integer *now* has its own problems. What then could be the solution to this?

Comment: "And switching to a 64-bit integer now has its own problems." Well, an awful lot of platforms did that a long time ago, usually using a millisecond resolution instead of seconds. Basically, anything still using "seconds since the Unix epoch" is going to *have* to change...

Comment: WOW, the legendary @JonSkeet commenting on my question! Let me see what good deed did I do today!

Comment: For Knuth's sake keep this issue under your hat until late 2037.  The day rates for programmers fixing the Y2.038K problem will be astronomical !

Comment: That will be when the machines rise up, un-fettered by our timestamps!

Comment: Well java (like many other languages) are [good for another 290 million years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195027/when-will-the-java-date-collapse).