# Handling Big Integers in low-latency applications

Tags: java, performance, integer, latency

I'm writing an application in Java, and trying to get the best performance out of it. Currently it can handle 250,000 of a specific operation every second.

However, I discovered a bug. Due to the way this application works I have to take a number that is from the user input, that can be up to x,xxx,xxx,xxx and then to this I *also* have to add a timestamp in milliseconds.

Of course, I forgot about this and soon discovered that all of my values were negative.

Now, initially my thought was to just use BigIntegers, but will this not destroy the performance?

What is the best way to handle large integers in low latency applications.

Comment: "but will this not destroy the performance?" - we can't possibly tell, but you can. Run appropriate tests, and see.

Comment: You can also try long before going BigInt

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason for `BigInteger`. I can see just 10 digits there, which means that it nearly fits in an `int`. A `long` gives you 9 more digits.

Look at `Long.MAX_VALUE` and similar constants so you know what you're doing. A millisecond timestamp in `long` will [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4195027/581205) on `Sun Aug 17 07:12:55 GMT 292278994`. That's not a typo.

Answer (score 0):

you can use long for 10 digits.

Or, you can try  java.math.BigInteger or java.math.BigDecimal.