# What is the max year that java.sql.Timestamp can handle?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date, timestamp

I am trying to create a maximum date in my program with the following:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

Date maxDate = new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE);
...
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(maxDate.getTime());
```

If I am correct `maxDate.getTime();` returns with the value of `Long.MAX_VALUE` so it doesn't really matter, I could have written simply `new Timestamp(Long.MAX_VALUE);` Am I right?

My problem is that my program gives the following exception at this point:

> java.sql.SQLException: Year out of range.

So what is the maximum long value that can be passed to Timestamp?
Or is there anything else I am missing here?

I am using an Oracle database if it matters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The ISO standard's years are from 1 to 9999.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum year `java.util.Date` can handle is year 292278994

> [When will the java date collapse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195027/when-will-the-java-date-collapse)

while the maximum year value for `java.sql.Timestamp` is 9999

Pretty sure thats how it works due to this error i kept getting:

`ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0`

Comment: I found [IBM knowledge center, which said the same thing too](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/el/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0053436.html).