# Limitation on year amount in org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils

Tags: java

Why does `org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils` have in its source code a limitation on the number of years?

```
if (val.get(Calendar.YEAR) > 280000000) {
    throw new ArithmeticException("Calendar value too large for accurate calculations");
}
```

I wanted to know, why exactly 280 millions, not for exmaple 285. I guessed already, that we won't have java anymore. Also I know, that Long can hold 292278994 years in milliseconds.

Comment: Ask the implementor of the code

Comment: The year 280 million AD? Well, I'd bet we won't have Java anymore by then.

Comment: @Thomas: no enough to calculate the end of the universe. And maybe you want to do that now, not when it's too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by Thomas there are woes due to date being stored in 64 bits. This guard was [introduced in 2004](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-lang.git;a=commitdiff;h=d19d4a852154ef1d38a842d88c34cac6505e5f01). See the test case for details and also bug [LANG-24](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-24).

Comment: Nice find. They already knew it by then: `Date endOfTime = new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE);`

Comment: Thank you. You showed me direction to explore.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'd have to guess but this is probably related to: [When will the java date collapse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195027/when-will-the-java-date-collapse)

Since year 280,000,000 is very close to the maximum of 292,278,994 there might be any anticipated accuracy problems, hence the message says

> Calendar value too large for *accurate* calculations.

Btw, we now know when the universe is going to end: Sun Aug 17 07:12:55 GMT 292278994  - ;)