# Will an int be 32bit and a long 64bit regardless of whether the system is 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: java, int, 32bit-64bit, long-integer

In java, is an int guaranteed to always be of 32bit size and a long of 64bit size regardless of whether the architecture is 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: It's by digging that I answered it? See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I answered it at the same time that I asked it. There is an option for that when you ask a question and the reasoning is to increase the content available on SO. No reason why SO shouldn't have "all the answers", even to simple questions.

Comment: I don't see how the question also provides the answer.  This page's answers gave me answer I was also seeking.  I actually "dug deep" before finding this page by reading https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html :  That "deep digging" did not provide the answer; this page did.  Too bad I can't downvote @Tala comments; they do sound rude.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java is platform independent.  So `int` is 32-bits, and `long` is 64-bit.

Answer (score 5):

`int` in Java is always 32-bit. No matter the OS type/architecture/whatever.

Comment: On a 32-bit OS, does a 64-bit long therefore have to get stored by something like splitting it across two 32-bit memory addresses?

Comment: @Cellepo, simply put, no.

Comment: Without further explanation (other than "simple"-mindedness), I have only been able to conclude that what I asked actually does seem closer to the truth:  "It doesn't matter whether a computer is 32 bit or 64bit, the RAM is always treated like a linear memory chain. Different points on this chain contain different bytes of the variable i.e different memory addresses contain different bytes of the variable." [https://www.quora.com/How-can-a-32bit-computer-store-a-double-or-long-long-type-number-as-the-size-of-double-is-8bytes-64bits]

Comment: That Quora link also quotes, "Therefore, storing variables is not related to the fact that the cpu is 32bit or 64." So a 32bit OS doesn't necessarily have 32bit addresses, but that seems a bit irrelevant anyways - if the system memory addresses (in general) are < 64bit (which seems independent of the OS bit architecture [32 vs 64]), it seems a Java long will get split across addresses... If there is a more accurate explanation, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 4):

The [Java Tutorial page on primitive data types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) specifies the fixed sizes and makes no mention of underlying architecture having any influence

> int: The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive).
>
> long: The long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer.
>   It has a minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a maximum
>   value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive). Use this data type
>   when you need a range of values wider than those provided by int.

Comment: I agree exactly, and that same page/reason is why I eventually had to find this page.  Thank you for asking.