# How can I detect integer overflow on 32 bits int?

Tags: java, integer, bit-manipulation, integer-overflow, integer-arithmetic

I know such topic was asked several times, but **my question is about overflow on full 32 bits of int**. For example:

```
  11111111111111111111111111111111 +
  00000000000000000000000000000001 =
  00000000000000000000000000000000   //overflow!
```

I found [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c) with similar question about this, however the algorithm is not perfect.

```
  11111111111111111111111111111111 +
  00000000000000000000000000000000 =
  00000000000000000000000000000000  //overflow!
```

Is there any simple, fast, safer way to check this ?

Comment: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/NUM00-J.+Detect+or+prevent+integer+overflow

Comment: BTW, Java int is always 32 bits (regardless of the architecture that your given JVM is running on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017752/will-an-int-be-32bit-and-a-long-64bit-regardless-of-whether-the-system-is-32-or]):  "By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -231 and a maximum value of 231-1" (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).  So the 32-bit specification here seems to be a bit irrelevant/moot.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

## `Math.addExact` throws exception on overflow

Since Java 8 there is a set of methods in the [`Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class:

- [`toIntExact(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact(long))
- [`addExact(int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#addExact(int,int))
- [`subtractExact(int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#subtractExact(int,int))
- [`multiplyExact(int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact(int,int))

…and versions for long as well.

Each of these methods throws [`ArithmeticException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) if overflow happens. Otherwise they return the proper result if it fits within the range.

Example of addition:

```
int x = 2_000_000_000;
int y = 1_000_000_000;
try {
    int result = Math.addExact(x, y);
    System.out.println("The proper result is " + result);
} catch(ArithmeticException e) {
    System.out.println("Sorry, " + e);
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/cAlYwX).

> Sorry, java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow

Answer (score 26):

```
long test = (long)x+y;
if (test > Integer.MAX_VALUE || test < Integer.MIN_VALUE)
   // Overflow!
```

Comment: Are x & y assumed to be long's themselves?  If they were instead int's, I don't think this would work (since the overflow would go undetected before the long cast); am I correct?

Comment: You are not correct. X gets cast to long before addition (precedence). long+int the int gets converted to long and you end up with long+long. Therefore the entire operation is done at 64 bit precision.

Comment: Ah ok so the cast has precedence over the addition operator.  Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Try this way:

```
boolean isOverflow(int left, int right) {
    return right > 0
            ? Integer.MAX_VALUE - right < left
            : Integer.MIN_VALUE - right > left;
}
```

From: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/NUM00-J.+Detect+or+prevent+integer+overflow

Comment: Overflow in `isOverflow(-47483648, -100000000)` is not detected.

Comment: This is not an overflow actually :)

Answer (score 3):

Overflow can be detected by a logical expression of the most significant bit of the two operands and the (truncated) result (I took the logical expression from the MC68030 manual):

```
/**
 * Add two int's with overflow detection (r = s + d)
 */
public static int add(int s, int d) throws ArithmeticException {
    int r = s + d;
    if (((s & d & ~r) | (~s & ~d & r)) < 0)
        throw new ArithmeticException("int overflow add(" + s + ", " + d + ")");
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Java 8's `addExact` is coded as `if (((s ^ r) & (d ^ r)) < 0)`.

Answer (score 3):

The most intuitive method I can think of: calculate the sum (or difference) as a `long`, then convert that sum to an `int` and see if its value has changed.

```
long longSum = (long) a + b;
int sum = (int) longSum;
if (sum == longSum) {
    // sum contains the correct result
} else {
    // overflow/underflow
}
```

Remember that on modern 64 bit processors, working with `long`s is no less efficient than working with `int`s (the opposite may be true). So if you have a choice between checking for overflows or using `long`s, go for the latter.