# Reverse digits of an integer: How to find out if the number have overflown?

Tags: java, integer

I am trying to solve a problem:

> Given a 32-bit signed integer, reverse digits of an integer, returns 0 when the reversed integer overflows.

My solution is:

```
public int reverse(int x)
{
    int reversedNumber = 0;
    boolean isNumberNegative = x < 0;
    x = Math.abs(x);
    while (x >= 10)
    {
        reversedNumber = reversedNumber * 10 + (x % 10);
        x = x / 10;
    }
    reversedNumber = reversedNumber * 10 + x;
    return isNumberNegative ? -1 * reversedNumber : reversedNumber;
}
```

My problem is with the overflow, how do I find out if the `reversedNumber` have overflown without using `Math` utility class or `long` and then checking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect integer overflow on 32 bits int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233582/how-can-i-detect-integer-overflow-on-32-bits-int)

Comment: Its for addition, and the solution asks to use Math utility class, I am looking for a solution without using the utility class.

Comment: Identify all possible inputs that can overflow, and handle them separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the conversion of `int` to `long` and vice versa, as a `long` bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and smaller than `Integer.MIN_VALUE` will overflow when casted back to `int`, this can be seen in the last 2 lines:

```
public int reverse(int x) {
    long reversedNumber = 0;
    boolean isNumberNegative = x < 0;
    x = isNumberNegative ? -x : x;
    while (x >= 10) {
        reversedNumber = reversedNumber * 10 + (x % 10);
        x = x / 10;
    }
    reversedNumber = reversedNumber * 10 + x;
    reversedNumber = isNumberNegative ? -reversedNumber : reversedNumber;

    int result = (int) reversedNumber ;
    return reversedNumber != result ? 0 : result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do this like that, without any casting:

```
public int reverse(int x) {
    int reversedNumber = 0;
    int digitCount = 1;
    x = Math.abs(x);
    while (x >= 10) {
        if(digitCount >= 9 && willOverflow(reversedNumber)){
            return 0;
        }
        reversedNumber = reversedNumber * 10 + (x % 10);
        x = x / 10;
        digitCount++;
    }
    if(willOverflow(reversedNumber)){
        return 0;
    }
    reversedNumber = reversedNumber * 10 + x;
    if(reversedNumber < 0){
        return 0;
    }

    return reversedNumber;
}

private boolean willOverflow(int reversedNumber) {
    int tmpMultiply = reversedNumber * 10;
    int tmpDivide = tmpMultiply / 10;
    return tmpDivide != reversedNumber;
}
```

If i believe you can check if integer will overflow, by multiplying it by 10 and then dividing it by 10. If value at the end is different than passed value, you can assume integer will overflow in next iteration (if there will be next iteration).