# if-else-if: getting an unexpected negative output

Tags: java, if-statement, negative-number

So i have this program, where when I select the area and type, the DP will generate.[image]

The problem is, when I select another type (tipe-45 and tipe-54), the result is showed in minus. What is the problem?

```
if(rb1.isSelected() && t1.isSelected()){
        hargabangunan.setText("90000000");
        luas_tanah_asli.setText("60");}
    else if(rb1.isSelected() && t2.isSelected()){
        hargabangunan.setText("120000000");
        luas_tanah_asli.setText("90");}
    else if(rb1.isSelected() && t3.isSelected()){
        hargabangunan.setText("150000000");
        luas_tanah_asli.setText("110");}
    
    else if(rb2.isSelected() && t1.isSelected()){
        hargabangunan.setText("100000000");
        luas_tanah_asli.setText("70");}
    else if(rb2.isSelected() && t2.isSelected()){
        hargabangunan.setText("130000000");
        luas_tanah_asli.setText("110");}
    else if(rb2.isSelected() && t3.isSelected()){
        hargabangunan.setText("170000000");
        luas_tanah_asli.setText("120");}
   
    else if(rb3.isSelected() && t1.isSelected()){
        hargabangunan.setText("120000000");
        luas_tanah_asli.setText("80");}
    else if(rb3.isSelected() && t2.isSelected()){
        hargabangunan.setText("140000000");
        luas_tanah_asli.setText("120");}
    else if(rb3.isSelected() && t3.isSelected()){
        hargabangunan.setText("200000000");
        luas_tanah_asli.setText("140");}
    
    int htl = hargat*75/100;     
    tst.setText(Integer.toString(htl));
    
    int lta = Integer.parseInt(luas_tanah_asli.getText());
    int ltth = ltt - lta;
    tsa.setText(Integer.toString(ltth));
    
    int hga = Integer.parseInt(hargabangunan.getText());
    int hgaa = hga+lta*hargat+ltth*htl;
    harga.setText(Integer.toString(hgaa));
   
    String hharga;
    hharga = harga.getText();
    int tharga = Integer.parseInt(hharga);
    int dp = tharga*20/100;
    dpf.setText(Integer.toString(dp));
```

Comment: You are doing calculations with some rather large numbers there. Have you checked if what you are trying to calculate even fits in the `int` datatype? Maybe the numbers are to big and you are experiencing [integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo)

Comment: As a quick fix: try changing all your `int` variables to `long`. It might only be needed on the `hga` and `hgaa` variables, but it just might to the trick.

Comment: changing to 'long', its work. Guess Im forget about this data type. thanks anyway

Comment: not enexpected at all...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `int` but you should use `long`. Integer can't be used in here as the value is just too big and overflows.

Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html to see available data types and compare maximum values that you can fit into them.

Use `Math.exact` and similar methods to immediately get an exception when value overflows. See [How can I detect integer overflow on 32 bits int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233582/how-can-i-detect-integer-overflow-on-32-bits-int)